# Are plugin dependencies defined in setup.py or in a requirements file?

Tags: python, plugins, frameworks, setup.py, requirements.txt

[install_requires vs requirements files](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/) says:

> Whereas install_requires defines the dependencies for a single project, Requirements Files are often used to define the requirements for a complete Python environment.

Does this mean, that distribution packages (P), which are plugins for other distribution packages (F), which build a framework, should neither occur in the setup.py / install_requires of F nor of distribution packages (L), which are other libraries, that use F, but in the requirements file, which specifies the installed distribution packages of a virtual environment (V)?

P depend on F. L depend on F. V depends on L and P.

L and F leave the decision open about which P to use. The decision is made by V.

setup.py / entry_points are defined in P. pkg_resources.iter_entry_points() is used in F.

Ps can either be:

- exclusive (e. g. Windows or Unix implementations of an entry point; only one plugin alternative is installed in V)
- coexistable (e. g. image format plugins of a graphics framework; multiple plugins can be installed in V)

Here I'm mainly talking about the "exclusive" case.

Where can I find an example for distribution packages, which form a framework, and others, which are plugins to the former?

Comment: There is no concept of exclusive extras if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Re-reading your question, I would say that whoever builds `U` might need to add `D1` and/or `D2` to `U`'s list of dependencies or leave that choice to whoever installs `U`. -- A `requirements.txt` file is not strictly necessary (I am not sure why you mention this in the question).

Comment: @sinoroc I have rewritten my question completely. Mapping of old to new letters: D1/D2 -> P, B -> F, C -> L, U -> V.

Comment: Your reasoning seems correct to me. I think this is how I would do it as well. The plugins (P) should not be listed in any `install_requires`.

Comment: You can use `importlib.metadata` from the standard library instead of `pkg_resources` to find plugins entry points: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/creating-and-discovering-plugins/#using-package-metadata

Comment: `pytest` plugins might be a good example of this principle in the wild https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/writing_plugins.html